# Meaning of "chafing"

Tags: word-meaning

> The Don puffed on his cigar and said, "Santino, what do you think?"
>   Hagen knew what Santino would say. Sonny was **chafing** at being under
>   the Don's thumb.

What is the mean of chafing here? I've found several meaning of that word in a [dicitionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/search/english/?direct=1&multi=1&q=chafing)

Is meaning **3.**

> Become or make annoyed or impatient because of a restriction or
>   inconvenience

suitable here?

Comment: Misquoting the "at" as "a" makes this example a lot more incomprehensible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Become or make annoyed or impatient because of a restriction or inconvenience

Is the right definition here.

If you look at the next few lines it makes more sense.

> The Don puffed on his cigar and said, "Santino, what do you think?" Hagen knew what Santino would say. Sonny was **chafing** at being under the Don's thumb. *He wanted a big operation of his own. Something like this would be perfect.*

Sonny didn't like being controlled by the Don. He wanted to have some control of his own - which he would get if this operation was set up.

Answer (score 2):

Your given definition is a good choice. Sonny is annoyed/impatient because Don has power over him.

Answer (score 2):

It is a metaphor in this example. Chafing is rubbing which causes heat or irritation and in this case the unstated comparison is with a dog or similar creature struggling against (for example) leather restraints in a desire for freedom. Sonny is looking for some way to escape Don's control.

Edit: in fact, it's really a mixed metaphor as Sonny is said to be under Don's thumb. However, both phrases are really clichés: metaphors that have lost their power by constant repetition.